# Firebase Database Structure for blog app

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

1)  Is it better to structure the database :

```
   blogapp
            -User
                id
                name
                 ...
            -Post
              id
              users
               -a unique id
                          -userId
                          -contentOfPost
```

2) Use a seperate node for UserPost

```
blogapp
     -User
     ...
    -Post

    -UserPost
     -unique id
               -userId
               -PostId
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes use a seperate `UserPost`:

```
Users
  userid
    name: userx
    email: userx@gmail.com
  userid1
    name:usery
    email: usery@gmail.com

UserPost
    userid
      author:userx
      postcontent: content_here
      posttitle: title_here 
    userid1
      author: usery
      postcontent: content_here
      posttitle: title_here
```

more info here:

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html